# How does empty() work with a boolean expression?

Tags: php

A guy learning PHP sent me some code that has me scratching my head.  He's getting `$_POST` input, putting it in variables, and then:

```
if( !empty($id && $name && $email) ) {
    //do something
}
```

My first inclination was that passing multiple variables as an argument would throw an error, but it evaluates successfully.  Am I incorrect that `empty()` should NOT take a boolean expression?  Or - if I'm right - why does it work?

Comment: Since 5.5, `empty` can take an expression rather than just a variable, but that's still a very strange way to write that code.

Comment: It's the same as `if( $id && $name && $email )`

Comment: @iainn Thanks - I wasn't aware of that update [empty() supports arbitrary expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php).  You're also right that it's strange!  It wasn't the only thing that I pointed out to him as unconventional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* pass an expression to `empty` rather than a variable (since PHP 5.5), but with an expression like that you lose half of the benefit of using `empty`. `empty` checks that variables are set as well as evaluating their "truthiness". When you give it an expression like that, the individual variables within the expression are *not* checked to exist by `empty`. The expression is just evaluated as a boolean.

So if you used separate `empty` checks, you would get the check that the variables exist as well as the check that they are `!= false`

```
if(!empty($id) && !empty($name) && !empty($email))
```

But when you use

```
if (!empty($id && $name && $email))
```

You will still get into the `if` block if all the variables are set and have non-false values, but you'll get undefined variable notices if any of them are not set.  It's basically the same thing as not using `empty` at all, like this:

```
if ($id && $name && $email)
```

But if your guy is setting these variables from `$_POST`, they *will* be set, (if they weren't in `$_POST` he'd get undefined index warnings at that point) and the `empty` here is pointless anyway.